# How to find correct jar file of Spring Data JPA and Spring version

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA and facing with an exception of jar version.

This is my pom:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.10</mysql.version>
    <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
    <spring-security-version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring-security-version> 
    <spring-data-solr.verion>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-solr.verion>         
    <springbatch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
    <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.1.1</liquibase.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.3.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>   
    <spring.social.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring.social.version>                        
</properties>
```

This is my class:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

}
```

I received an error warning on Eclipse with message:

```
The type org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

It seem my Spring data jpa jar version is incorrect, but I don't know find correct version. My Spring verion: 4.2.4.RELEASE is latest

How to fix this error? Thank so much !

Comment: I would suggest using the Spring IO `import` POM to manage all of these versions for you--they make sure to keep them in sync.

Comment: is your meaning I should search and refer in Spring IO ?

Comment: Can u try Spring data 1.9.2 ... This works for me with Spring 4.2.4 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Try using spring bill of materials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a POM, it means you're using Maven, and Maven has a plugin called dependency on which you can call `dependency:list` that will list all your jar dependencies together with their versions.

Just call at the root of your project (given that you're using a starter):

```
./mvnw dependency:list
```

and you will list your jars:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXXXXX 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list (default-cli) @ xxxxxxx ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
```

You can also use `dependency:analyze-duplicate`, `dependency:tree` or `dependency:analyze-report` to check everything is declared once. Check the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) for this plugin, it is really useful when you're facing dependencies issues.

Here's a sample of dependency:tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ouaknine ---
[INFO] com.rdlopes.ouaknine:ouaknine:war:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.bundles:json:jar:20090211_1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.193:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.mattbertolini:liquibase-slf4j:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
```

On my MacBook Pro, I simply call in the Terminal:

```
macbook-pro-de-rui:ouaknine rui$ ./mvnw dependency:list | grep jpa
[INFO]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: It's cool ^^ I have tried and I can use Spring data jpa 1.9.2 version.. I think from now I will don't worry about issue and conflic jars, thanks @rdlopes

Comment: I'm really glad for you, I used to pull my hair sometimes without knowing this plugin existed ^^

Comment: *FYI:* If you do nothing but dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile`, you'll end up with `spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar` (among many other jars), where the `QueryByExampleExecutor` interface can be found.

Answer (score 5):

The place to go to find the version compatibility is https://www.mvnrepository.com/ You put in your version and it will show the associated libs and their versions. Cool site. It will even show you how to enter your POM.
For your spring data jpa, I entered "Spring data jpa" in the search, clicked on the library, then clicked on your version "1.10.3". If you scroll to the bottom, it will show the associated compile dependencies and their versions.