# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library

Tags: java, mysql, logstash, elastic-stack

I am getting java version and mysql-connect-java.jar compatibility issue with logstash.

can any one tell me which version of mysql-connect-java.jar is compatible with which version of java?

Error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
```

my current java version is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

I have tried with below mysql connector jar files but every one fails.

```
mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar
mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar
mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar
```

Logstash config file is mysql.conf

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prbi"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => ""
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar" #tried above every jar
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" #tried com.mysql.jdbc.Driver too
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "%{id}"
        clean_run => true
        statement => "SELECT * from tmp_j_summaryrepor"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['http://localhost:9200']
    index => "prsummaryreport"
    document_type => "prsummaryreport"
    document_id => "%{id}" # It is a Primary Key of table
    }
    stdout { codec => json_lines } 
}
```

Comment: on my maven project with java 8, i have mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar. try it to see if it works.

Comment: @Sahzeb, do you know where is it documented? which version is compatible with which jar?

Comment: @Shahzeb, same error, with mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar version, can you tell me your exact version of java?

Comment: if you don't specify version in pom.xml file (maven project). it is resolved by maven in spring boot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006156/how-to-find-correct-jar-file-of-spring-data-jpa-and-spring-version

Comment: Where is your driver located? Have you tried the full path for `jdbc_driver_library`?

Comment: yes path is correct and it is located in same directory

Comment: @Michael Dz, you were right, it is a path problem, when i shift file to other directory it is working fine

Comment: I resolved problem by shifting jar file from /etc/logstash/conf.d/ folder to Home directory in ubuntu. finally worked with java version 8 with mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar

Comment: @JunedAnsari feel free to post your comment as an answer and accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

for logstash 6.2.x and above, prefer adding the drivers under:

```
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/
```

and rather keep the `jdbc_driver_library` empty. this has been quoted in many of the elastic.co forums too.

Comment: Thanks! This fix works for Logstash 7.1 on Mac Mojave

Answer (score 2):

Logstash can't load the driver because it's looking for the driver in the wrong place, you should always specify the full path to a driver e.g.:

```
jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I specified the full path of `jdbc_driver_library` to: `"/opt/drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"`

It was working prior to a restart and then suddenly started throwing the error.

I found out that for some reason the `jdbc.jar` file was corrupted, the size had changed to **0KB**. I redownloaded the Jar, dropped it in the full path and restarted.

So you might just want to check that your jdbc file is fine. It should not be 0KB.